# clearInterval not working for me before start setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 1 function which set another function in `setInterval`

```
var intval;
function loadvideo(video_id)
{
    clearInterval(intval);
    var intval=setInterval(function() { callAjax(video_id); }, 3000);
}
```

And here is the function `callAjax`

```
function callAjax(vid){
    console.log(vid);
}
```

When i refresh my browser first time it will working OK, but whenever i call `loadvideo` function, i see 2 different values in console by `loadvideo` function. That means old value is not clearing and `setInterval` calling `callAjax` function 2 time. It will increase call every time when i call  `loadvideo` function. I am doing anything wrong here?

What i want to do is only update  video_id`into interval when`loadvideo` function call.

Comment: remove the var in  `var intval=setInterval(function() { callAjax(video_id); }, 3000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use var keyword in function. This keywords define local variable and you set intertval into this local variable, not into global variable defined over loadvideo function.

```
var intval;
function loadvideo(video_id)
{
    clearInterval(intval);
    intval=setInterval(function() { callAjax(video_id); }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
var intval;
loadvideo(178)
function loadvideo(video_id)
{     intval=setInterval(function() { callAjax(video_id); }, 1000); }
function callAjax(vid){
    console.log(vid);
    clearInterval(intval)
}
```